# useEffect refetch everytime when data is changed.How to achive it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this custom hook to fetch my data but i have problem its fetch only once on render i know its becouse array on use effect its empty but when put there **setPartData** and **url** or **data.data** it becomes like **infinite loop** how to avoid this.

How to achive its refetch every time when data is change without burining my computer CPU.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const apiStates = {
  LOADING: "LOADING",
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
};

export const useApi = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    state: apiStates.LOADING,
    error: "",
    data: [],
  });

  const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });

  useEffect(() => {
    setPartData({
      state: apiStates.LOADING,
    });
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPartData({
          state: apiStates.SUCCESS,
          data,
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setPartData({
          state: apiStates.ERROR,
          error: "fetch failed",
        });
      });
  }, []);

  return data;
};
```

And component where i use it

```
 const { state, error, data } = useApi("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/albums");

  const albums = data.data;
  switch (state) {
    case apiStates.ERROR:
      return <ErrorMessage>{error || "General error"}</ErrorMessage>;
    case apiStates.SUCCESS:
      return (
        <CartWrapper>
          {albums.length > 0 ? (
            albums.map((album) => (
              <CardWithEdit
                width={"23rem"}
                height="16rem"
                color={album.color}
                bckImg={album.bckImgUrl}
                key={album._id}
                link={`/albums/${album._id}`}
                editLink={`edit/${album._id}`}
                id={album._id}
              >
                {album.name}
              </CardWithEdit>
            ))
          ) : (
            <h1>No albums yet</h1>
          )}
        </CartWrapper>
      );
    default:
      return <Loader />;
  }
```

Delete where i need to reload page to get updated state

```
const CardWithEdit = ({
  width,
  height,
  bckImg,
  color,
  children,
  link,
  editLink,
  id,
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setState(!state);

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/albums/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });

    handleClick();
  };

  return (
    <Card width={width} height={height} bckImg={bckImg}>
      <AlbumtTitle color={color}>{children}</AlbumtTitle>
      <LinkButton background={color} to={link}>
        See more
      </LinkButton>
      <IconWrapper>
        <div>
          <Link to={editLink}>
            <AiOutlineEdit />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
          <AiOutlineDelete
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </IconWrapper>
      {state && (
        <Dialog
          handleClick={handleClick}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          deleteText={"Delete"}
        />
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: When do you want it to fetch?

Comment: @KubaKluzniak , when do you know the data has changed?

Comment: when i delete one of "albums"

Comment: when you open the dialog ? or when you click the confirmation ? when does the app brake ?

Comment: when click confirmation.

Comment: Well this doesn't make any sense, please show the stack trace. Because the `CardWithEdit` doesn't use the `useApi` hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another state variable, where you can store the recently deleted element ID. The useEffect will have to be hooked to that variable. If that ID, changes, the useEffect will fetch new data.

```
const [deleteID, setDeleteID] = useState(null);  //update this in the delete component

  useEffect(() => {
setPartData({
  state: apiStates.LOADING,
});
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setPartData({
      state: apiStates.SUCCESS,
      data,
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    setPartData({
      state: apiStates.ERROR,
      error: "fetch failed",
    });
  });
  }, [deleteID]); //useEffect will only fire when delete ID changes.
```